# Constructing an approximation in $C_{00}$ sequences for a sequence in $l_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation

I want to show that $l_1$ is separable. I got the tip to

1. Show that $C_{00}(\mathbb{N}) \subset l_1(\mathbb{N})$ (This I accomplished)
2. Construct a sequence $(b_n)_n \in C_{00}(\mathbb{N})$ which approximates a given sequence $(a_n)_n \in l_1(\mathbb{N})$ arbitrarily well.
3. Finally, construct a countable set which approximates $(b_n)_n$

My problem is within 2 and 3. I don't know what it means to approximate mathematically and how to do it. What are the constraints to call something a properly approximation?

I have looked through a lot of literature, but I couldn't find a section explaining how approximation really works. I don't need a fully fledged solution for the problem described above, more like the general idea how to approach such a task and how approximations work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part 2, given $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $a_n \in \ell^1$, you want to find a sequence $b_n \in c_{00}$ with $\| b_n-a_n \|_{\ell^1}<\epsilon$. A convenient way to do this is to have $b_n$ just be a truncation of $a_n$. Figure out how to determine where to do the truncation.

I would say that part 3 is poorly worded. The issue is that $b_n$ is just fixed, so I can cheekily answer with $\{ b_n \}$ and technically be correct. But I can tell what they are trying to do because you said what the final goal is. The final goal is to find a fixed countable subset of $c_{00}$ (*not* depending on the choice of $b_n$) which contains a sequence converging to $b_n$. The natural choice of this is $c_{00} \cap \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. You should show that $c_{00} \cap \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $c_{00}$, then by part 2 it must be dense in $\ell^1$ also.

Comment: This sounds very logical and thank you very much for pointing out that poorly wording in part 3. From your description I think I know how to proceed in this proof.

But one thing is still unclear to me, what does it mean to do an approximation. Is there any good literature you can recommend, where I can read about this, or are you able to add some point on this question in your answer?

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies Approximation is in some sense what analysis is all about, so this is a very open-ended question. I can point you to analysis textbooks that I liked, but that's about it.

Comment: I will be very happy to have your suggestion. But for sequences I have found a good idea. Basically I was told, that it is about giving an epsilon-error which tells by which error a sequence is estimated, such that $|a_n - b_n| < \varepsilon\\$

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies This kind of functional-analysis-but-not-quite analysis I learned out of Royden and Fitzpatrick.